# How can I modify my data model to have a computed property?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am returning JSON data from a remote server which holds some information. (The product name and the date).

I want to modify the date output in my handlebars template. [Here is a JSBin with my code.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/iJiZOjU/1/edit)

Should I use a property in order to change the format of the date? Or there is a better way to do that? If yes, what should I do?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Ember Helper:

The better way to do it is to use an [Handlebars Helper](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/) to convert your date into a useable format. The reason a helper is better than a computed property, is it can be reused throughout your code anywhere you need to format a date in the template.

I have [updated the JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/iJiZOjU/4/edit) to use this helper.

### Helper:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('dateformat', function(value) {
    // Use moment, or alternatively use JavaScript date and return your own custom string
    return moment(value).format("DD/MM/YY"); // Change to suitable format. See http://momentjs.com/docs/
});
```

### Usage:

```
{{dateformat item.date}}
```

### Note:

This example uses the [MomentJS library](http://momentjs.com/) to convert the date into format `DD/MM/YY` but obviously you can change this.

It is possible to do the conversion without using this external library, using the standard JavaScript `date` object. The helper just needs to return the formatted string.

---

## Computed Property:

To do it as a computed property requires a little more effort. You can see a [working demo of this here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/APISofAG/1/edit?html,js,output). The demo uses a modified version of your `localeDate` function.

### Ember Object with Computed Date Property:

So create a `HistoryItem` object that has the computed property.

```
App.HistoryItem = Ember.Object.extend({
    localeDate: function() {
        var dt = new Date(this.get('date'));
        return dt.toLocaleDateString() + " " + dt.toLocaleTimeString();
    }.property('date')
});
```

### Update Model:

The model is a plain object, you need to create an instance of the `HistoryItem` for each item in your history.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        // Get the history
        var history = App.JsonRequestFromRemoteServer.history;

        var result = [];

        // Create item as history item
        history.forEach(function(item){
            result.push(App.HistoryItem.create(item));
        });

        // Return the result as the model
        return { history: result };
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

---

To address why [your JSBin here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/iJiZOjU/14/edit) didn't work:

You were trying to use `property("history.@each.date")`, to create a computed property on each item in the collection.

Unfortunately what this does is provide what's called an *Aggregated Property*. You can read more about [aggregated properties here](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/), but essentially that would give you one property on your history object based on all the dates in the collection. Not a single property on each item as desired.

I do think this is an area of Ember that should be better covered in the documentation, you're not the first person to think you can add computed properties to collections that way.

Comment: Hello, 

thank you for your response. That is exactly what i want to do. But could you tell me how i could transform my date into to a usable format with a property(In order to know both ways)?

I think that i need to combine the [Ember.computed.map](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_computed_map) with a property. But i cannot figure out how to do it...

Thank you.

Comment: @Scoot. OK take your time. Thank you again.

Comment: @kokeroulis I have updated to include the computed property method.

Comment: Yes, that help me.Thank you. But i have only one last question.
This what i [had](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/iJiZOjU/14/edit) tried before you update your jsbin. Could you explain me why my approach does not work? Thank you again.

Unfortunately i cannot up vote your answer because i have not enough reputation points.

Comment: @kokeroulis I have updated to include why your approach didn't work. Hope that helps. :)